# UI is not updating react & redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm beginner in react and redux, I have action which posts JSON on API and then receives list, this action called from button click, this all process works good but after populating data ui is not updating

Action:

```
import * as types from './actionTypes'
import { postMessage } from '../api/messaging'

function postToAPI(msg, dispatch) {
  dispatch({ type: types.MESSAGE_POSTING });

  postMessage(msg, (messages) => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.MESSAGE_POST_DONE,
      messages: messages
    });
  });
}

export function postMessageAction(msg) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    postToAPI(msg, dispatch);
  }
}
```

Reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes'

const initialState = {
  messages: []
}

export default function messages(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.MESSAGE_POST_DONE:
      return {
        ...state,
        messages: action.messages
      }
      this.forceUpdate();
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Main container:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CounterApp />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

CounterApp:

```
class CounterApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { state, actions } = this.props;
    return (
      <Messaging />
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  messages: state.default.messages.messages
}))(CounterApp);
```

Messaging:

```
class Messaging extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MessageList messages={this.props.messages} />
        <Message />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default connect(state => ({
  messages: state.default.messages.messages
}))(Messaging);
```

Message list:

```
export default class MessageList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        {
          this.props.messages.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <Text>
                { item.body }
              </Text>
              )
          })
        }
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

My MessageList component does not updates when messages changed. I read difference between props and state but i dont know how to pass data to state.

### Update:

My state in messaging connect looks like this why i used default

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What you've labeled "Reducer" is actually a duplicate of your action creators. Please fix. I suspect you're mutating your state in the reducer; it's generally where people go wrong.

Comment: My bad, i posted reducer incorrectly please check updated question.

Comment: Can you post all your reducers and also the code where you create your store?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks strange. Firstly you need to connect to redux only in one component "Messaging"

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  messages: state.messages.messages
});
@connect(mapStateToProps);

class Messaging extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    messages: PropTypes.object
  }
  render() {
    const { messages } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <MessageList messages={messages} />
        <Message />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Then use MessageList like dumb component to receive and render data.

```
  export default class MessageList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    renderMessages(item, index) {
      return <Text>{item.body}</Text>;
    }

   render() {
     const { messages } =  this.props;

     return (
       <ScrollView>
        {messages.map((item, index) => this.renderMessages(item, index))}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: messages: state.messages.messages < here i'm getting error state.messages is undefined, please check my updated question

Comment: As I can see your state had array [39] before you corrected it. Bring it back and then just change connected state

    messages: state.default.messages.messages

Answer (score 1):

A few things I noticed are:

1. From what I can see there's no `default` object in the state (you wrote `messages: state.default.messages.messages`).
2. You shouldn't use `forceUpdate()` in your reducer.
3. While it won't break anything, the `CounterApp` component is using `connect` without using any of the props.

Try this instead:

Reducer:

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes'

const initialState = {
  messages: []
}

export default function messages(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case types.MESSAGE_POST_DONE:
      return {
        ...state,
        messages: action.messages
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

CounterApp:

```
class CounterApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Messaging />
    );
  }
}
```

Messaging:

```
class Messaging extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MessageList messages={this.props.messages} />
        <Message />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  messages: state.messages.messages
}))(Messaging);
```

Comment: messages: state.messages.messages < here i'm getting error state.messages is undefined, please check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

At a guess I'd say your connect statement wants to be

```
messages: state.messages
```

rather than

```
messages: state.default.messages.messages.
```

Also from what I can see I don't think you need the connect statement in CounterApp, it's not doing anything.

I'm not sure if the returned messages should replace or be merged with the existing messages but your reducer should be either

```
case types.MESSAGE_POST_DONE:
  return {
    messages: action.messages
  }
```

if it's replacing the existing list or

```
case types.MESSAGE_POST_DONE:
  return {
    messages: [...state.messages, ...action.messages]
  }
```

if you want to merge them.